# How to create a new dotnet core application that has both auth and EF?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I can create a new dotnetcore app that has authentication/identity using the command line:

```
dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
```

How can i include entity framework in the project also?

Comment: I would take a look at Jon Skeet's blog post on how to ask a good question. codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question You've provided enough information for me to give you an answer, but the question is lacking a little in detail. Which version of the .NET Core SDK are you using, for instance?

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

You already have it in your project

#### Long form answer

After creating your application, it should have Entity Framework as a dependency. I'm assuming that you're running the .NET Core 2.0 SDK.

Here's the output from my machine

```
$ dotnet new mvc --auth Individual --name testForStackOverflow
The template "ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)" was created successfully.
This template contains technologies from parties other than Microsoft, see https://aka.ms/template-3pn for details.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on testForStackOverflow/testForStackOverflow.csproj...
  Restoring packages for  testForStackOverflow/testForStackOverflow.csproj...
  Restore completed in 40.17 ms for  testForStackOverflow/testForStackOverflow.csproj.
  Restore completed in 40.17 ms for  testForStackOverflow/testForStackOverflow.csproj.
  Restore completed in 25.25 ms for  testForStackOverflow/testForStackOverflow.csproj.
  Generating MSBuild file  testForStackOverflow/obj/testForStackOverflow.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file  testForStackOverflow/obj/testForStackOverflow.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore completed in 2.84 sec for  testForStackOverflow/testForStackOverflow.csproj.


Restore succeeded.
```

I then look a look at the csproj which was generated:

```
$ cd testForStackOverflow/
~/testForStackOverflow$ ls
app.db                        Data        Startup.cs
appsettings.Development.json  Extensions  testForStackOverflow.csproj

appsettings.json              Models      Views
bower.json                    obj         wwwroot
bundleconfig.json             Program.cs
Controllers                   Services
~/testForStackOverflow$ cat testForStackOverflow.csproj 
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-testForStackOverflow-AD382505-1A70-4A75-8059-1E0E3897A088</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="app.db" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The important line of the csproj is here:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
```

This is a reference to the [ASP.NET Core metapackage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/). This package contains all of the common ASP.NET Core NuGet packages, including Entity Framework Core - as per this screen shot from NuGet (captured a few moments ago)

[image: ASP.NET Core metapackage showing EF Core provided]

This means that part of the package restore operation included restoring EF Core into your project.

I would say that you should take a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/#the-model) for EF Core - the link should take you directly to the section labelled "The Model". You don't need the stuff in the preceding section (labelled "Get Entity Framework Core") as you already have it.

Of course, if you're using version 1.x of the .NET Core SDK, then it's a slightly different story.